# Does the compiled prepared statement in the database driver still require compilation in the database?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

In the Oracle JDBC driver, there is an option to cache prepared statements. My understanding of this is that the prepared statements are precompiled by the driver, then cached, which improves performance for cached prepared statements.

My question is, does this mean that the database never has to compile those prepared statements? Does the JDBC driver send some precompiled representation, or is there still some kind of parsing/compilation that happens in the database itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the implicit statement cache (or the Oracle Extension for the explicit Statement Cache) the Oracle Driver will cache a prepared- or callable statement after(!) the close() for re-use with the physical connection.

So what happens is: if a prepared Statement is used, and the physical connection has never seen it, it sends the SQL to the DB. Depending if the DB has seen the statement before or not, it will do a hard parse or a soft parse. So typically if you have a 10 connection pool, you will see 10 parses, one of it beein a hard parse.

After the statement is closed on a connection the Oracle driver will put the handle to the parsed statement (shared cursor) into a LRU cache. The next time you use prepareStatement on that connection it finds this cached handle to use and does not need to send the SQL at all. This results in a execution with NO PARSE.

If you have more (different) prepared statements used on a physical connection than the cache is in size the longest unused open shared cursor is closed. Which results in another soft parse the next time the statement is used again - because SQL needs to be sent to the server again.

This is basically the same function as some data sources for middleware have implemented more generically (for example prepared-statement-cache in JBoss). Use only one of both to avoid double caching.

You can find the details here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/stmtcach.htm#g1079466

Also check out the Oracle Unified Connection Pool (UCP) which supports this and interacts with FAN.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this answers your question: (sorry it is powerpoint but it defines how the prepared statement is sent to Oracle, how Oracle stores it in the Shared SQL pool, processes it, etc).  The main performance gain you are getting from Prepared statements is that on the 1+nth run you are avoiding hard parses of the sql statement.

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fchrisgatesconsulting.com%2FpreparedStatements.ppt&rct=j&q=java%20oracle%20sql%20prepared%20statements&ei=z0iaTJ3tJs2InQeClPwf&usg=AFQjCNG9Icy6hmlFUWHj2ruUsux7mM4Nag&cad=rja

Oracle (or db of choice) will store the prepared statement, java just send's it the same statement that the db will choose from (this is limited resources however, after x time of no query the shared sql will be purged esp. of non-common queries) and then a re-parse will be required -- whether or not it is cached in your java application.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I'm after. I understand how Oracle stores the prepared statement in the shared pool and such but I'm trying to understand what it is that is cached in the Oracle JDBC prepared statement cache. The PPT (excellent, BTW) touches on the topic but doesn't go into detail.