# Delete from with a variable number of arguments

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, transactions

I want to use transactions with this query

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN(?, ?, ?)
```

But the number of IDs is variable.
Sometimes I have 2, sometimes 5 etc.

Can I rewrite it differently so it accepts a single `?` argument which contains all IDs?

Code:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$st = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN(?, ?, ?)');

foreach( ... ){

  $st->execute(array($id1, $id2, $id3));
  // but here I may have only 2 IDs to pass, or 5 etc.
}

$pdo->commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
$questionmarks = str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['foos'])-1) . "?";    
$query = "DELETE from `employee_customeraccount` WHERE `id` IN ($questionmarks)";
$st = $db->prepare($query);
```

Comment: thanks but I don't think you understand. I only want to prepare the query once, so it cannot change...

Comment: @Alex You cannot use the same prepared statement for different numbers of IDs.

Comment: @Alex +1 You only have to prepare it once. Then just bind and execute for each element you have. Place all executions inside a transaction and you will get a near optimal performance for any RDBMS.

Comment: @LS_dev you **cannot** prepare once with **arbitrary** number of placeholders - this is the point. It is often worth to read the question and the comments.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know, but you can prepare for one placeholder and execute an arbitrary number of times. This answer is not directly related to question, but is a solution!

Comment: @LS_dev I see now. One by one would work. But I doubt it worth the mess anyway. Not to mention that giving +1 to the answer that contradicts with your comment seems illogical to me.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of the "XY problem" you asked,

> Can I rewrite it differently so it accepts a single ? argument which contains all IDs?

No.

there is also very little point in it - multiple execution is not a thing that have to be pursued at any cost.

But speaking of the *real* problem you face,

There obviously could be solution or two. Though, as like all XY-askers you omit most important details, we can only guess. Say, you can save up all the ids and then delete all of them at once, after the loop but before commit.

Or just prepare your deletes every time. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed number of parameters, like 10 in `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?,?)`. Prepare this query and execute it repeatedly with portions of 10 parameters:

```
for ($offset = 0; $offset < count($yourIdArray); $offset += 10) {
    $params = array_slice($yourIdArray, $offset, 10);
    if (count($params) < 10)
      $params = array_pad($params, 10, $params[0]);
    $st->execute(...);
}
```

The final set of parameters is simply padded by an ID which is already contained in the array (no side effect).

(Note: I do not have PHP available nor am I a PHP guy. So take the above as pseudo-code.)

I am not sure if the approach of chunking parameters in statements/queries makes sense with Sqlite/PHP which I would not expect to have a query/statement cache or high cost of query/statement prepraration. I have used this approach myself on Oracle databases primarily to avoid "query/statement cache pollution" which would result from having queries/statements with different number of parameters.

Comment: What query cache for a DML query you are talking about?

Comment: Sqlite would not even benefit from this approach even if it had a query cache because it is not a "query". I will edit may answer. As an aside, Oracle's JDBC driver features a statement cache, which is probably not true for Sqlite/PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772038/does-the-compiled-prepared-statement-in-the-database-driver-still-require-compil